# Creating a dynamic column chart with Highcharts and Angular to visualize object data

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, highcharts

I have this is json response

```
{
    "dates": [
        "2023-05-01",
        "2023-05-02",
        "2023-05-03",
        "2023-05-04",
        "2023-05-05"
    ],
    "values": [
        {},
        {},
        {
            "Apple": 454,
            "SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super": 191,
            "Samsung's new variant which goes beyond": 3
        },
        {
            "OPPO F19 is officially announced on April": 4980,
            "Huawei’s re-badged P30 Pro New Edition": 41424,
            "MacBook Pro 2021 with mini-LED display": 2535,
            "Basic Data": 293,
            "Samsung Galaxy Book S (2020)": 1181,
            "Style and speed. Stand out on HD video calls": 378, 
        },

       {}
       
    ],
}
```

I want like this:
[image]

can you help me how to bind object to column. currently I am doing like this:

```
 public createChart(container, options, chartName = null) {
        const chartOptions = this.getOptions();
        const chartData = [];
    
        options.forEach((data) => {
          const chartDataObject = {
            name: [],
            data: [],
            color: '',
            fillColor: {}
          };

          
          chartDataObject.name = Object.keys(data.values)
          .filter((key) => Object.keys(data.values[key]).length !== 0) // Filter out empty objects
          .map((key) => key); // Extract the names
        chartDataObject.data = Object.values(data.values)
          .filter((value) => Object.keys(value).length !== 0) // Filter out empty objects
          .map((value) => (value ? Object.values(value)[0] : 0)); // Extract the names
          chartDataObject.color = data.color;
          chartDataObject.fillColor = {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 150],
            stops: [
              [0, data.color],
              [1, Highcharts.color(data.color).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
            ]
          };
          chartOptions.xAxis.categories = data.dates;
          console.log(chartDataObject);
          chartData.push(chartDataObject);
        });
        chartOptions.series = chartData;
    
        const element = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(element);
        chartOptions.chart['renderTo'] = element;
    
        this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
        return this.chart;
      }
```

I am try to create column chart xAxis display all the data yAxis display object
that object we have name and value if object is empty bind 0 if object is there i need to bind

Comment: Can you create a demo on StackBlitz? It's hard to know what are the passed values for `container`, `options`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a stacked column chart with categories on x-axis. The most important thing is to adapt your data to the series structure required by Highcharts. You can do that for example in the way below:

```
const series = [];

repsonse.values.forEach((values, xVal) => {
  Object.keys(values).forEach((key, index) => {
    if (!series[index]) {
      series.push({
        data: []
      });
    }
    series[index].data.push({
      name: key,
      x: xVal,
      y: values[key]
    });
  });
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  ...,
  series,
  xAxis: {
    categories: repsonse.dates,
    min: 0,
    max: repsonse.dates.length - 1
  }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mdv6rp2L/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data

Comment: First thaku so much 
If i have color code array list then how to bind for example 
[{'apple':'#00629e','SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super':'#00873d','Basic Data','#00923f'}]

mouse hover that tooltip i want show name and values(see above live demo ) not series 1 and color code 
one more this observe if values is very less that time chart is appear for example  {
            "Apple": 3333333,},
        {
            "OPPO F19 is officially announced on April": 3999,
        },{
         "Basic Data": 100,}
 so in that case only is coming apple line "basic data" is not coming

Comment: Hi @Lane T, I am not sure how the colors array is structured in the response, but it is enough to set a color in data, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1fc8s52a/ For a better tooltip experience, you can enable `shared` option and format content in the way you want.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek Thank you for reply now I am able bind color also I am facing one issue if  xAxis data is empty but yAxis data is there that case chart is not appear i want show chart that case if data is empty also for example-  {
   { "dates": [
        "2023-05-01",
        "2023-05-02",
        "2023-05-03",
        "2023-05-04",
        "2023-05-05"],
    "values": [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}
]}

Comment: In this case, you can add a simple condition which adds one empty series if there is no series at all: `series: series.length ? series : [{}]`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/46nfw1qo/

Comment: Thank you for reply it's working as now I need one more help if we have multiple column line with color so when mouse hover ` tooltip: { headerFormat: "{point.x <br>", pointFormat: '<span style="color: {series.color}">{point.name}</span>: {point.y}<br>'},`if I have  three date=["2023-05-01","2023-05-02","2023-05-03"] first date i have red color ,second date green color and third date color red if i mouse hover first date color it's highlighting third date color because it's same color. I want mouse hover specific color should come not all the column I don't want use  shared: true.

Comment: @Lane T, Please reproduce the problem in jsfiddle.

Comment: In this (http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mdv6rp2L/) example when you mouse hover one color highlighted all column color and other color is disable mode color but i want if i mouse hover color no effect I want 

Note: My requirement is when I hover color other color should not affected anything

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! You just need to disable `hover` and `inactive` states. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ayogez9u/

Comment: Thank you so much for reply it's working as per my expected.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what are the values for `container` and `options`, but this should resolve the issue according to your current code.

As mentioned in @ppotaczek's answer, you need to provide the value in structure so that HighCharts is able to render the chart correctly.

In summary of the below code,

1. `keys` - Extract all the property names from the object in the `data.values` array.
2. `series` - Transform from the `keys` array into an array of objects containing each series data with `name` and `value` properties. Default the `value` as 0 if the object in the `data.values` array doesn't contain the property (`key`).
3. `categories` - Categories are the label for the x-axis, which should use `data.dates` as a value.

```
createChart(container: any, options: any[], chartName = null) {
  const chartOptions = this.getOptions();

  const chartData: any = [];

  const keys = this.data.values
    .map((x: any) => Object.keys(x))
    .reduce((acc: any[], cur: any[]) => [...acc, ...cur], [] as any[]);

  chartOptions.series = keys.map(
    (key: any) =>
      ({
        name: key,
        data: this.data.values.map((y: any) => y[key] ?? 0),
        //color: /* Your color value */,
        //fillColor: /* Your fillColor setting object */,
        } as any)
    );

  (<AxisOptions>chartOptions.xAxis)!.categories = Array.from(this.data.dates);

  const element = document.createElement('div');
  container.appendChild(element);
  chartOptions.chart!['renderTo'] = element;

  this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
  return this.chart;
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-picvtb?file=src%2Fmain.ts)